Configure An Ansible Job in Rundeck, using Terraform/OpenTofu
I've successfully managed to create a Terraform file for configuring Rundeck to run an inline BASH script. However, I want to take things further by figuring out how to automatically configure a job that makes use of Ansible.
From reading the provider documentation for a job, it looks like I need to configure the step_plugin within the command block that references the Ansible plugin. This takes a type and a config as shown below:

Unfortunately, unlike the other areas of the documentation, it does not list possible values for the type so I have had to guess, with no success thus far. I always get an error message similar to:

Workflow has one or more invalid steps: [1: [The step plugin type "com.batix.rundeck.plugins.AnsiblePlaybookInlineWorkflowNodeStep" is not valid: Plugin not found: com.batix.rundeck.plugins.AnsiblePlaybookInlineWorkflowNodeStep]]

I did look up the list of plugins from the GET /plugins/list endpoint and tried these names but they didn't work:

I also tried lots of variations of camelCase, snake_case etc on the words "ansible" "playbook" and "inline" with no combination seeming to work. I saw that in the returned API output, it stated that builtin was set to false. However, if I go to artifact/index/configurations then I can see the Uninstall button suggesting that they are installed.

Question
Does anybody know how to configure an Ansible job in Rundeck through Terraform/Tofu and can provide a basic example?

Have you tried creating a similar job manually via the Rundeck UI and exporting it to one of the export formats? For a job that uses a plugin that should include the expected plugin type name as the type attribute of the plugin selection in whatever export format you choose.

The rundeck/rundeck Terraform provider implements creating and updating using Rundeck's "import" API in JOB-XML format, so matching the plugin identifier you find in a JOB-XML export should select the plugin you want.

You must add the node_step_plugin block (inside the command block) pointing to the plugin's name and the config. A good way to see which options elements you need is to create a mockup ansible job, export it in YAML format, and then see the job definition content to apply on the terraform config subblock.
The terraform rundeck deployment file looks as follows (a very basic example tested on Terraform 1.8.0 and Rundeck 5.2.0):
terraform {
  required_providers {
    rundeck = {
      source  = "rundeck/rundeck"
      version = "0.4.7"
    }
  }
}

provider "rundeck" {
  url         = "http://rundeck_url:4440/"
  api_version = "47"
  auth_token  = "rundeck_auth_token"
}

resource "rundeck_project" "terraform" {
  name        = "terraform"
  description = "Sample Created using Terraform Rundeck Provider"
  resource_model_source {
    type = "file"
    config = {
      format = "resourcexml"
      file = "/path/to/your/resources.xml"
      writable = "true"
      generateFileAutomatically = "true"
    }
  }
  extra_config = {
    "project.label" = "Ansible Example"
  }
}

resource "rundeck_job" "ansiblejob" { 
  name              = "Ansible Test"
  project_name      = "${rundeck_project.terraform.name}"
  node_filter_query = "tags: ansible"
  description       = "Ansible Playbook Test"

  command {
    node_step_plugin {
      type = "com.batix.rundeck.plugins.AnsiblePlaybookWorflowNodeStep"
      config = {
        ansible-base-dir-path = "/path/to/ansible/config/"
        ansible-become = "false"
        ansible-binaries-dir-path = "/path/to/ansible/executable/"
        ansible-playbook = "/path/to/your/playbook/ping.yml"
        ansible-ssh-passphrase-option = "option.password"
        ansible-ssh-use-agent = "false"
      }
    }
  }
}


Thank you very much! I was almost there and was mixing up the node steps vs steps.
In case others hit this issue, if one wishes to use a "step" instead of a "node step", one would change node_step_plugin to step_plugin and change the type value to com.batix.rundeck.plugins.AnsiblePlaybookInlineWorkflowStep. The Rundeck docs explaining the difference between step and node step is at: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/getting-started/jobs/pieces-of-a-job.html#workflow-steps-vs-node-steps
